# Hibernate self ManyToMany save problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class Node 
**Node.java**

```
public class WebPage implements BusinessObject {
  @Id
  private Long       id;
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "childnodes")
  private Set<WebPage> references;   // nodes contained by this node
}
```

My requirements :

1. One node can reference many nodes.
2. One node can reference it self.
3. One node can be referenced by many nodes or not.

I want to do something like this :

1. Node A -> Node B (Node A references Node B and so on)
2. Node A -> Node C
3. Node A -> Node D
4. Node B -> Node E
5. Node B -> Node C

All steps run OK except the 5th one. I have an exception : `Unique index or primary key violation:` How can i tell Hibernate to DO NOT try to insert Node C but instead update it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not on Hibernate behalf but on a bug in my code :\

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the code which tries to create all entities. However, the flow would be something like,

1. Create/Retrieve all nodes required for Node B
2. Populate Node B with all those
3. Save Node B with `cascade-insert`